# How to open a webpage with Firefox/Chrome on server and save it to a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, server-side

I want to open a webpage with Firefox or Chrome on server (Apache) using command line, and save it to a file:

> firefox http://example.com > mypage.html //it doesn't work

this command should execute browser javascript code and returns what it prints like on normal browsing.

Is it possible with Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: why downvotes? client side javascript on server side is not a trival problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a server-side programmatically-controllable browser, use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).